# Get BIM 360 Project Type parameters

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We have a custom application that creates BIM 360 project using Forge API endpoint. For creating project, "project_type" is a mandatory parameter and list of allowed values are available here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/parameters/#project-type.

However, we see that the list is updated since we developed the application and has lot of possible project type values now. So I have two questions:

1. Is there an endpoint available to get these allowed project-types dynamically? I tried but couldn't find this.
2. Can we have custom project-type value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re.#1 - unfortunately, no methods to list canned project types.
However, if you are using BIM 360, you can type arbitrary types. So you can specify any names when you are using API. It was a change based on the user request.

re. #2 - as mentioned above, you can name any type with BIM 360.

Note: The above does not apply for ACC project. There is a wish against it:
ACSADMIN-1764: “Customer API Wish: ability to define custom project types” (for ACC project)